# GPS ground coverage

Tags: geolocation, gps, maps, android-maps-v2

Here is my idea to track my sprayer coverage on the farm with an android app.

1. Use get??Location to provide GPS Coordinates
2. Use Coordinates to plug into polyline with Maps API v2
3. Set polyline width according to boom width. (conversion will require pixel to distance conversion at different zoom levels.

How would I display ground coverage with a polyline if the footage on the map will change with zoom level? Correct me if I'm wrong, but the polyline uses pixels for a defined width. My idea would require the user to input the width of the sprayer in feet and then the program would have to then calculate a polyline width based on the zoom/pixel ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not draw a poly line, because your spray path forms a closed polygon.
So you must draw a polygon with line width = 0 (or minimum line width);
Fill the polygon.

For such precision farming usuallay better GPS devices are used with centimeter accuracy. (using RTK)

Comment: Good idea to fill the polygon. I would guess the easiest way would be to have the program take the coordinates and calculate two more at the radius in two directions from the position of the phone and to continually recalculate the length dimension as the phone changes position. 

I can't seem to think of a way to get it to create separate polygons as the driver changes direction. If I drove around the perimeter of the field the polygon would automatically fill the entire area showing I had sprayed everything.

This is for my personal use so Im not worried about RTK level accuracy.